# java- possible to call rollback function after transaction is commited?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a program where I have the ability to extract words from a file and insert those words into a table in MySQL.

My program works fine where it can commit the transaction after all the words from the file is inserted into the table. If anything happens in between the transaction, then nothing is inserted to the table since autoCommit is set to false.

I was wondering since there once a transaction is committed, the records are permanent in the table , is there a way to undo such transactions, if there are tons of different transactions, how do I manage to undo them?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Rollback is not UNDO, it is intended to rollback a ***partially completed transaction*** _prior to commit_.  Wishing it was UNDO and asking why it isn't is not productive.  That is not how Rollback is defined.  If you want UNDO capability you must provide it yourself.

Comment: It is intended to rollback a partially completed transaction. So in my case, as I am in process of inserting to the table before commit, if anything happens, those records will not be inserted at all. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: It is up to you to group multiple individual operations into transactions.  Then, you can make sure that either ALL of the operations happen atomically, or NONE of them happen.  Rollback was never intended as an UNDO operation after the fact.

Answer (score -1):

If a commit succeeds then its done, complete, you can't roll it back at that point. so it should not be done

Edit:
to be more clear the con.rollback should be used within a catch block if con.comit fails

Comment: So it's not possible to undo it?

Comment: why not though, then what's the purpose of connection.rollback?

Comment: When you call commit(), you complete/close the current transaction. Thus, since rollback() undoes any changes in the current transaction (as per the javadoc), it will effectively do nothing.

Comment: I see. But why does rollback in MYSQL work differently where after you committed, you can run ROLLBACK and it undo everything?

Comment: are you sure its committed

Comment: Yes it is committed because i check the db. but i mean if i run the rollback command in sql workbench, it works